# How to rewrite history with git replace?

Tags: git

I applied some replacements to a repository with `git replace`. Now I would like to finalize that and rewrite the history according to the replacements. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) for this.